# How can i select data with linq part by part of rows?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linq

i want to select data from datatable or sql table or list 50 rows by 50 rows. Forexample:

var list = from x in dtable  select x ----- > first 50 rows Click next button for GridView next 50 rows . And than 50 rows whli clicking next button to monitor GridView?

For Example Data :

```
        static DataTable GetTable()
        {
            //
            // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
            //
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

            //
            // Here we add five DataRows.
            //
            table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

            return table;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can utilize .Take() and .Skip() methods as appropriate.

[Ref 1](http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/gridview-objectdatasource-linq-paging-and-sorting)

[Ref 2](http://www.dbtutorials.com/display/linq-to-sql-paging-cs.aspx)

[Ref 3](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/71/Search-Engine-Friendly-Custom-Paging-with-the-GridView-and-LINQ-to-SQL)